# How to inject a List or any non-mockable object into @Tested Spring beans in a JMockit testcase

Tags: java, junit, mocking, jmockit

I am trying to use JMockit- 1.45 to test spring based services. Strangely, I am unable to mock List objects. I have also noticed similar behavior for other non-mockable classes mostly from `java.util.*`. 
How can I achieve the below mentioned in Jmockit?

```
class ServiceA{
 @Autowired
 private List<SomeObj> list;
 .......
}

Class ServiceATest{
  @Injectable
  private List<SomeObj> list;
  @Tested
  private ServiceA serviceA;
  .............
}
```

I am getting below error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.List is not mockable
```

Comment: I don't have a good answer for this and would be interested to see one.
Since List is not mockable, my workaround was to not use @Tested and use a constructor (in which you can provide other mocks and a real list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Tested` on the `List` field, initializing it with the actual list to be injected.